# running the event loop in tf federated

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I tried the code mentioned on homepage of tensorflow federated site....

https://www.tensorflow.org/federated

Got the error:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
```

Complete code:

https://github.com/shantanuo/stack_question/blob/master/tensorflow_federated.ipynb

How do I run the sample code?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a Jupyter + asyncio issue. See [README.md](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/docs/tutorials/README.md) for more information.

1. Install nest_asyncio.
2. Use nest_asyncio to patch asyncio.

```py
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

Answer (score 0):

By design asyncio does not allow its event loop to be nested. This presents a practical problem: When in an environment where the event loop is already running it’s impossible to run tasks and wait for the result. To fix this, run the following code in your Jupyter Notebook:

```
!pip install --quiet --upgrade --user nest_asyncio

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

This will solve your problem.